# NodeMCU-12E - Conflict between I2C and SPI

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I have SPI SD-card module connected to nodeMCU, and it's worked well. Next I try to connect I2C sensor, and it doesn't work. Looks like SPI conflicts with I2C, because when I disconnect SD-card, I2C sensor get worked.

[image: Schematic]

I use Arduino IDE with esp8266 board framework.
The key code:

```c
Adafruit_BME280 bme; // I2C
bme_status = bme.begin(0x76);  
...

const int chipSelect = 4; // Don't worked with other values!!!
sd_status = SD.begin(chipSelect);
```

Another question is why SD card worked only with chipSelect=4?

Comment: io 4 is D2 on NodeMCU. you use it for I2C and as SS pin for SD card? what is your real wiring?

Comment: D2 is connected to bm280.SDA pin. I drew this schema from my real board

Comment: The trick this two isn't worked together. When I connect both devices - bme.begin always return false, but MicroSD worked.

Comment: How are you making a conclusion that your SPI bus specifically is messing with your I2C bus? Are you sure that the NodeMCU is not current limiting itself when you plug in your SD card? I don't see a correlation of how your I2C bus being interfered by your SPI bus unless there was some really weird electromagnetic phenomenon going on.

Comment: then why do you use D2 as CS for SD pin if it is wired to D8? btw. you can use any pin as CS for slave.

Comment: Juraj - thank you friend! It's all worked now! I don't understand it correctly about IO pinout on node.